# Thread Runnable vs AsyncTask Life Cycle

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I would like to better understand what happens to a `Thread` or a `AsyncTask` when activity is destroyed.

So in this scenario, a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` would be started from activity, and user hits home button and `onDestroy` gets called triggering GC before either Thread of AsyncTask had a chance to finish.

Which one is more likely to run till completion in this scenario `Thread/Runnable` or an `AsyncTask` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both will run**

But the problem is if you have a reference to the killed activity on Thread of AsyncTask it will leak, and that is a problem you need to solve to make long running tasks synchronized with UI

If you've got a bigger task, I'd suggest you to spin up a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which are more easy to handle in Android context

Comment: By leak, do you mean activity will be kept alive until thread finishes?

Comment: Yes, as in object, which causes a memory leak, but not the actual activity(UI)

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask based on thread so there is no huge difference in it's behaviour both will run after onDestroy. To avoid this behaviour you could use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) or manually stop execution of AsyncTasks/Threads in onDestroy method.

Comment: Thanks I'm actually interested in my logic finishing inside the running Thread, but dont want the complexity of service implementation.